# Laptop cannot run on battery - dies instantly when removed from mains power

Tags: battery, charger, toshiba-laptop

My laptop is a Toshiba Satellite L640.  If I remove the laptop charger, my laptop will instantly die, so I can only use the laptop whilst plugged in.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: … buy a new one? Get a free replacement if it's still under warranty? Batteries are not meant to live forever.

Comment: what the price of a new battery?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, your battery is dead. Batteries have a limited lifetime – or, more precisely, a limited number of full charges until their condition becomes worse.

At some point, your battery may fail to sustain power for even a couple of minutes. Or, they may fail entirely. This is not unusual, it's just a sign that you need a new one.

If your laptop is still under warranty (check if there are separate warranty conditions for batteries!), you can get a free replacement. Other than that, your only option is to buy a new one for around $70 to $100 (you're looking at the battery model LTPTB073 for your laptop).

Comment: yes, i think so too. But unfortunately, the warranty for my laptop has been a long time has expired.
To buy it, do I have to buy the exact same type of battery with the previous one. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you need to buy the same battery type like the one you had.

Answer (score 1):

there may be a problem on your laptop battery. I've been there on my vaio laptop VGN-FZ140E. I eventually replace my laptop battery because the warranty is not valid. after I replace the battery problem is not there anymore and my laptop back to normal.

Comment: yes, I will try to replace my laptop battery. I hope your advice can work on my laptop. :)

Answer (score 0):

Either something inside the laptop is broken, or, more likely, the battery has worn out.  For a new battery, if not under warranty, you're looking at around the £100.

Comment: yes, maybe it's a constraint on my battery. I will soon try to replace my laptop battery. but I still have to save up to buy a new battery. thanks for your suggestions.. :)